# How to stop particle system with a timer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system, particles

so I have a simple code that Spawn particle when player stay at a trigger. But the particles keeping turn on and i want to turn off after a few seconds. What i have to do?

```
 if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            PlayerManager.health += 1;
            MyParticleEffect.SetActive(true);

            Debug.Log("e key was pressed");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to change this value you can turn off the loop property and play with the duration.

If you want to change this dynamically, its best to use StartCoroutine:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

This is used like a timer, and you can turn the particle system off when the timer elapses.

Comment: how can i turn off the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Your particle system is probably set to 'loop'. Set the loop property of the particle effect to false.